# javascript - FileReader onloadstart not fired in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, mozilla, filereader

So, I'm using a `FileReader` to read a user-selected file and in Chrome everything works smoothly. However, in Mozilla, the `onloadstart` event is not being fired. [The official page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) states that such event listener does exist. Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
function handleUploadFile() {
    if(window.FileReader) {
        const fileChooser = document.createElement('input');
        fileChooser.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        document.body.appendChild(fileChooser);

        fileChooser.addEventListener('change', e => {
            const selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
            if(selectedFile) {
                const filename = selectedFile.name.split('.');
                const extension = filename[filename.length - 1];

                if (_.indexOf(['csv', 'dat'], extension.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
                    alert('The file must be of type ".csv" or ".dat"');
                    return;
                }

                const f = new FileReader();
                f.readAsText(selectedFile);

                f.onloadstart = (ev) => {
                    console.log('start');
                };

                f.onloadend = (ev) => {
                    console.log('end');
                    const content = ev.target.result;

                    this.parseFile(content, selectedFile.name, extension);
                };

                f.onerror = (ev) => {
                    console.error(ev.target.error);
                };
            } else {
                console.error('Failed to load file');
            }
        });
        fileChooser.click();
        document.body.removeChild(fileChooser);
    } else {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onloadstart event is fired before you listen to it. So you need to change the order like this:

```
const f = new FileReader();

f.onloadstart = (ev) => {
    console.log('start');
};

f.onloadend = (ev) => {
    console.log('end');
    const content = ev.target.result;

    this.parseFile(content, selectedFile.name, extension);
};

f.onerror = (ev) => {
    console.error(ev.target.error);
};

f.readAsText(selectedFile); //moved this line to the bottom
```

Comment: great! it's working. but, do you have any idea why it was working in Chrome?

Comment: firefox seems to fire the event immediately, while chrome fires it in an later event loop iteration. So in chrome your listeners are attached when the event fires.

Comment: not working for me..